# How to upgrade API version in Swift Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am trying to upgrade Facebook API call version to 2.11 at the moment.

I can set API version in Facebook developer site, app's page -> Settings -> Advanced -> Upgrade API Version -> Upgrade All calls (v2.11) and Upgrade Calls for App Roles.

However, after I set up API version on the website, I can't find any place I need an update on my project.

**Question:**
After upgrade API version on the website, how can I upgrade API version in iOS Swift project?